# Hibernate - @OneToMany in @MappedSuperclass generates table for every child entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following entity which is a base entity for every other entity in the app:

```
@Audited
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    public static final long UNSAVED = 0;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Image> images;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<File> files;

}
```

My goal is to have two tables - **images** and **files** so that these two tables are shared to all entities that extend BaseEntity. I do realize that for that all entities that extend BaseEntity should have one shared id sequence.

And then I have two entities that are subtypes of the BaseEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Equipment extends BaseEntity {
  private String name;
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private EquipmentType type;
  private String model;
  private String serial;
  private Boolean status;
}

@Entity
@Table
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class News extends BaseEntity {
  private String title;
  private String summary;
  private String content;
}
```

Now, when I set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create-drop`, hibernate generates the following tables for me:

```
news, equipment, news_images, news_files, equipment_images, equipment_files
```

However, I would like to have four tables instead:

```
   news, equipment, files, images
```

I would really appreciate any help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the `@OneToMany` lists a `@JoinColumn(name="ID_SOMETHING")`. These two part column names `news_images` are join tables created by Hibernate if no `@JoinColumn` is specified.